# Embed Javascript in HTML Coding Best Practice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing my first html application. I have both JavaScript and jQuery embedded at the bottom of the html file.

1. Is it a good practice to mix JavaScript and jQuery together?
2. Currently, I am importing jQuery 3.3.1; what if next version comes out? How can I make the imported jQuery dynamic?

[image]

Comment: This is pretty brad and opinion based, so it's a little off topic. That being said a couple of comments: 1)  Be consistent and if you can't be consistent be obvious when you mix jQuery and straight vanilla JavaScript. I find the jQuery selctors and DOM traversal more powerful so I tend to stick to jQuery conventions. 2) Is auto upgrade a good thing? What if there is a breaking change or bug? Also a minor consideration here is caching of the library. I like to control when I update my libraries so I can test against change, instead of treating my users as unpaid testers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering your questions one by one.

1. First of all, you are keeping your scripts at the bottom of the page. And that is really a good practice to keep all the scripts at the bottom of the page so that it will not block rendering of the page.
2. Second, mixing JavaScript & jQuery code is completely a personal choice. But still, I would recommend going with either JavaScript or jQuery to maintain code consistency & it's understandability. It will be easier for other developers to understand code that is written in a consistent way. Though, there might be some points where you would like to prefer JavaScript to achieve performance & you should do that but such cases will be very few.
3. **Best Practice:** Write all your scripting code in separate file & take reference of that file in your HTML page.
4. Don't worry about the jQuery version updates. Current jQuery version is very very much stable, so even if the newer version comes up - you would not need to switch to that version until or unless you are blocked for some feature that is only available in the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

This will be your Jquery which is in your system

```
<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

and if you thinking according updates then you should go with CDN links

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is it best practice to add attributes like `language="Javascript"` to the `<script>` element, even if they should auto-resolve?

Answer (score 1):

1) JQuery is a JavaScript framework. You can write the same exact thing in plain JavaScript that you can in JQuery. The difference is that JQuery will often be shorter and perhaps easier to read. So in short they are meant to be mixed together.

2) Also, if a new version of JQuery comes out nothing will happen to your project. Jquery is just a bunch of plain Javascript that makes things easier for you. It won't stop working because a newer version is available.

Answer (score 0):

1. Jquery is Javascript I don't think it is bad practice to mix them!